# How To Sync Visual Studio Code Local Files With Mapped File Server?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is a simple description of my problem. If you need more information please inquire.

I am not seeing any way that you would be able to sync files from my local computer to another file server. Is there a way that this would be possible using Visual Studio Code and a mapped network drive file server?
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=sync&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Answer (score 7):

You can sync files to another machine via a plugin called 'ftp-sync' this will allow you to send files to a destination via the FTP or SFTP protocol. This plugin also allows automatic upload on save (which is awesome).

See Url: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukasz-wronski.ftp-sync

Comment: is  there also a plugin for smb-snyc?

Comment: If you are referring to a linux SMB share then you can use the FTP protocol to connect to this.

Comment: There used to be a plugin for Sublime Text that did this, but that's been abandoned and the creator never ported it to VS Code even though that's what he abandoned ST for =-\  I need a way to do this without FTP, just straight network write like the Sublime plugin did.